# UI grid not displaying data Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I do have a UI grid which displays the Group Name.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            enableSorting : false,
            columnDefs: [
            { name:'GroupName' ,enableCellEdit:false}
            ],


            data: [
            { 'GroupName' : groupData}
            ]
        };
```

For the data in UI grid , i am passing an Object array in the form of :

```
groupData = [{"GroupName": "Mathematicians"}{"GroupName":"Scientist"}]
```

But am not getting anything in the UI grid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your directive calling too..i.e the `html` part

Comment: <div id="Group_grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit class="groupslist"></div>

Comment: You just need to change your `data` assignment to `data : groupData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting one level too deep when passing the data.

Instead of (the equivalent of):

```
data: [ { 
    GroupName: [ 
       { GroupName: 'Mathematicians' },
       { GroupName: 'Scientist' }
    ]
} ]
```

you just want to pass all the data in the data property, so you get:

```
data: groupData
```

Comment: @PravinBhasker Please mark this as the "accepted" answer so people can see at a glance that this question is resolved.  Thanks and please!

Answer (score 1):

**Some observations :**

- Your **`$scope.groupData`** is not having a valid JSON.

  It should be `$scope.groupData = [{"GroupName": "Mathematicians"},{"GroupName":"Scientist"}]`
- Your **`gridOptions`** object should be like this.

  ```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
          data: 'groupData',
          enableSorting : false,
          columnDefs: [{ 
            field: 'GroupName',
            displayName: 'Group Name',
            name:'GroupName',
            enableCellEdit:false
           }]
          };
  ```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('uigrid', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'groupData',
            enableSorting : false,
            columnDefs: [{ 
              field: 'GroupName',
              displayName: 'Group Name',
              name:'GroupName',
              enableCellEdit:false
             }]
            };
            
            $scope.groupData = [{"GroupName": "Mathematicians"},{"GroupName":"Scientist"}]
}]);
```

```css
</style> <!-- remove this, it is just for jsfiddle --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script> 
<style>
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="uigrid">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```